# A good approach using BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to navigate between activities while coloring the current item on bottom navigation.

**What is the best approach to achieve this?**

Currently, on every activity when I'm using `BottomNavigationView` (in this case`com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`),

I'm duplicating almost the same code for navigating between activities which is hard to maintain:

1. Marking the current `itemId`
2. Setting the`setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` without the current `itemId`.

   ```
   jesta_bottom_navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.nav_do_jesta

   jesta_bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

       val intent = when (it.itemId) {
           R.id.nav_ask_jesta -> {
               Intent(this@DoJestaActivity, AskJestaActivity::class.java)
           }
           R.id.nav_status -> {
               Intent(this@DoJestaActivity, StatusActivity::class.java)
           }
           // Settings Activity
           else -> {
               Intent(this@DoJestaActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java)
           }
       }
       startActivity(intent)
       true
   }
   ```

**frame_bottom_navigation_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/jesta_bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/Widget.Jesta.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/jesta_bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_drawer_menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should have one Activity with one BottomNavigationView and selecting an item swaps the fragment displayed in the Activity

Comment: @MikeSpeed so I should treat the activities as fragments? can you explain why?

Comment: Well if it was me I would refactor all my Activities to be Fragments. This is what Google now suggests (one activity, many fragments). It means that you'll only need one BNV and you're not creating a new one every time you swap to a new screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an external library for doing this faster

- [AHBottomNavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)
- [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, do you have references for other good external libraries? (Not specific for navigationView)